# How to register a Service Workers with a custom scope when the current URL has query parameters?

Tags: web, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a website on "https://mypage.com", in it I want to register a Service Worker so that I can install my website (a PWA). The service worker lives in "https://mypage.com/PWA" and has no trouble getting registered the following way most of the time:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/PWA/sw.js', {scope: "" });
```

(registration at a scope that is broader than the location of the SW file is not a problem in this scenario because of unrelated code)

However, when the website has a query argument on the URL like "https://mypage.com/?isSearch=true" the scope of the registered SW is "https://mypage.com/?isSearch=true" and therefore cannot be used to install the website. On this project I cannot control when the website has query arguments or not so the website will unexpectedly have them.

I also tried to have `{scope: "/"}` but the registered SW doesn't let me install the website since the scope is "https://mypage.com/" and not "https://mypage.com"

Sometimes the website is in "https://mypage.com", and sometimes in "https://localhost:5000/Staged" for local development, ideally the solution would work on both.

**The question is**: how can I make sure that the SW is **always** registered to the root path of the website?

Answer (score 2):

The solution in the end was to use an absolute path when registering the Service Worker:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/PWA/sw.js', { scope: location.origin });
```

`location.origin` would end up resolving to, for example, "https://google.com" which would be a valid URL in my scenario.

That way it didn't matter that the current URL had query arguments since the registration was explicit and absolute.